# How to set third-party cookies in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, webview

Can third-party cookies be set in Flutter's WebView using **webview_flutter** package when showing offers to users in the app?

Can this be done in Flutter? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The webview_flutter provide the `CookieManager` class to manage the cookie. When you use it, you can set the cookie and delete all cookies.

```
final _cookieManager = CookieManager();
  const WebViewCookie(
    name: "test",
    value: "value",
    domain: ".posstree.com",
  ),
);
cookies = await _webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
  'document.cookie',
);
print(cookies);
```